# How can I find brick part number from a picture?

Tags: part-identification, bricklink

I found [some books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593276885) I like, but the book only give pictures of the parts. For example, this one

[image]

How can I know the part number (for example in bricklink) from the picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to start learning the nomenclature for those pieces.

For example the long straight pieces you have there with holes on top are "[Technic, Brick 1 x 12 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3895#T=C)"

The pieces with rounded ends are lift arms. You can browse through [the list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=137) of them here or take a stab at their descriptions using the width and number of pin holes. For example the purple on you have there is

- 1 hole wide
- 9 holes long
- as think as a normal LEGO brick (some are half that thickness)
- Bent with 6 on one line and 4 on the other

  so "[Technic, Liftarm 1 x 9 Bent (6 - 4) Thick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6629#T=C)"

Answer (score 4):

- I find [BrickSet](https://brickset.com/parts) a bit easier to browse for parts than BrickLink
- Alternately you could install LDD (Lego Digital Designer), find the name of the part, and then search with that name

Answer (score 3):

It's good application for android - parts are sorted and easy to fine necessary part.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.betab.partsguideforlegotechnic